# Workaround to see slideshare viewers tab information

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

The `viewers` tabs under `Analytics` have been broken from the last couple of months on `slideshare.net` (https://www.slideshare.net). I tried contacting their helpdesk multiple times but was not able to get a response.

It seems there is a javascript error (see attached picture). I was wondering if you think there can be a way around to get the viewers information?

[image]

PS: It seems that viewers pane display information from Google Analytics. Now the problem becomes how to pull information from Google Analytics?

Comment: Check the API responses